# touching window from inside of frameset

Tags: javascript, html

The server provide me a `frameset` to code into. so I don't have access to main `window` object. Is there anyway to touch `window.history`?
I want to use `window.history.pushState`, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy applies. Did you try `parent.history`